# Samsung keyboard in a Galaxy tab just got changed to white by Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung, keyboard

I use the built in Samsung keyboard in a Galaxy tab. It just got changed to white by Lollipop. How rude - I HATE it!  I've tried Swift Key and Google keyboard and dislike them both (no delete key, among other reasons). So am I just stuck with this unwanted white color, forced on me without asking?

Thanks

Comment: Your questions isn't really a question, though. Kinda more of a rant. Can you edit so other users can know if you're looking for alternative keyboard app suggestions or if it's possible to change the settings in the stock app...? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just started using a new keyboard app last week and totally love it. [Multiling O Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kl.ime.oh) can be configured any way you like including colors as well as adding and removing keys (like delete). The app can be a bit confusing at first, but if you mess with the settings for a while you'll find it to be great. Plus, it has almost no permissions and takes up hardly any memory.